# Observable of IDB does not return values

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to convert the promises from the indexDB library 'idb' to an Observable.
Putting values into the database works, but when initialising my service, I want it to check the indexDB for values to get.

To accomplish this I need to make sure the indexDB initialisation has finished before calling the getTable functions I have. So far the initialisation works, but reading the values afterwards doesn't.

```
private indexDB: IDBPDatabase<DatabaseSchemaV1>;
indexDB$ = new Subject<IDBPDatabase<DatabaseSchemaV1>>();

private initIndexDB$() {
        return from(
            openDB<DatabaseSchemaV1>(this.dbName, this.DB_VERSION, {
                upgrade(db) {
                    db.createObjectStore(IndexDBTable.TABLE1);
                    db.createObjectStore(IndexDBTable.TABLE2);
                },
            })
        ).pipe(
            map((indexDB) => {
                this.indexDB$.next(indexDB);
                this.indexDB = indexDB;
                return this.indexDB$;
            })
        );
    }


public getTableUserExercises$(): Observable<ExerciseTableItem[]> {
    if (!this.indexDB) {
        return of([]);
    }
    return from(
        this.indexDB
            .transaction(IndexDBTable.UserExercises)
            .objectStore(IndexDBTable.UserExercises)
            .getAll()
    );
}

public getTableTrainUnits$(): Observable<TrainUnit[]> {
    if (!this.indexDB) {
        return of([]);
    }
    return from(
        this.indexDB
            .transaction(IndexDBTable.TrainUnit)
            .objectStore(IndexDBTable.TrainUnit)
            .getAll()
    );
}

private getTables$() {
    return combineLatest([
        this.getTableUserExercises$().pipe(),
        this.getTableTrainUnits$().pipe(),
    ]);
}


constructor() {
        // this._indexDBSub = this.initIndexDB$()
        //  .pipe(map(() => this.getTables$()))
        //  .subscribe((values) =>
        //      console.log('In IndexDBSub after getTables: ', this.userExerciseTable)
        //  );

        // this._getTablesSub = this.getTables$()
        //  .pipe(
        //      map((values) => {
        //          console.log('Arrays in getTablesSub: ', values[0], values[1]);
        //      })
        //  )
        //  .subscribe((what) => console.log(what));

        const indexDB = this.initIndexDB$();
        const trainUnits = this.getTableTrainUnits$();
        indexDB.pipe(concat(trainUnits)).subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
    }
```

In the constructor you can see that I tried working with concat and mapping as well as with combineLatest calls from RxJS, but none of them got it to work. What works is calling a single observable and subscribing to it with the downside of having to wait for the indexDB manually:

```
this.getTableUserExercises$()
            .subscribe((values) => console.log(values));
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the entire example, but there is one thing that does not make too much sense to me.

In this line

```
indexDB.pipe(concat(trainUnits)).subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```

you are using the `concat` operator and you pass to it a function that returns an Observable. In such cases, i.e. the concatenation of a chain of Observables which have to be executed in sequence, you should use an operator like `concatMap`, which flattens the inner Observable and pass to the following `subscribe` the value notified by the inner Observable.

So the code should be

```
indexDB.pipe(concatMap(trainUnits)).subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```

Similar operators, i.e. operators that flatten the inner Observables, are `mergeMap` (aka `flatMap`), `switchMap` and `exuastMap`.

You may fins some inspiration to deal with typical rxJs uses cases in [this article.](https://medium.com/better-programming/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a)